# Logical operators with possible undefined value in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am getting a error and I don't fully understand why. I understand that it could be undefined and therefore I need to check if it exists but if I setup the code as below then I get the errors. However if I replace `{showDescription &&`  with `{isFeatureBlock && description &&` inline it works perfectly. Why does it not work if I assign it to a const?
*Note: I have simplified to focus on the main issue.*

**The Code**

`isFeatureBlock` is a boolean, `description` is optional string

```
const showDescription = isFeatureBlock && description

{showDescription && (
   <BlockDescription>
     {description}
   </BlockDescription>
 )}
```

**The Error**

1. 'Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: Can you explain what is this rows: `{showDescription && (
   <BlockDescription>
     {description}
   </BlockDescription>
 )}`? Is it object or something else?

Comment: It just returns a div with some text in it, though I noticed need to update errors as i included an error from something else. The object undefined is related to another issue. My mistake. The first error still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has no problems, but I assume in your real code, you use `description` in some place where a proper string is expected, and that is where the error is signaled. The reason why it works when you add `description &&` is that in that case its type gets narrowed in the right-hand side of `&&`.

For `description && SOME_EXP`, TypeScript narrows the type of `description` from `string | undefined` to `string` inside `SOME_EXP`, as it can statically determine that `description` will not be undefined there. This only works if you use the variable directly in the left-hand side of the `&&` expression though, so assigning it to a constant and using that constant won't work.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the explanation that is exactly what I needed, I did not realise the type would get narrowed was really confused!!